# Set "default" monitor to ALWAYS run apps in it instead of display#1

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, 15.10, monitor

In my system, there are two different monitors 2 (main) and 1 ( in right , for films or etc.).

When i use #2(main), logging in and opening an app or pressing Ctrl+Alt+T key, window opens in monitor 1, which is secondary for me and most of times turned off. To fix this i need to click on Nautilus launcher for example and then terminal will open on current screen, when focused window is in display i need.

How can i configure my system to run apps ALWAYS in my primary display (2), and move windows to another display with mouse only manually?

Comment: Hi Dmitrij, could be done, but would take a (very lightweight) background script to intercept new windows, if you want the two monitors to be connected continously. Would you fancy one?

Comment: I think i need to make it continuous, like most preferable.

Comment: You mean no script (which is also continuous)? Cool, but I am afraid there is no other option. Primary has no effect on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiz window placement plugin can be used to fix initial position for all windows.

1. Install Compiz settings manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it from dash or using `ccsm` command
3. Go to *Window Management* → Enable *Place Windows* then click on it to change its settings
4. On *General* tab, change *Multi Output Mode*: `Place across all outputs`
5. On *Fixed Window Placement* → *Windows with fixed positions*

   *New* → *Positioned windows*: `any` then close 
   Select its row again → *Edit* → Change *X Positions*, *Y Position*: `100`,`50` (as you like)